# Yum update file Error

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, yum

```
[root@ ec2-user]# yum update file*
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * amzn-main: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
 * amzn-updates: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package file.i686 0:5.30-11.34.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package file.x86_64 0:5.34-3.37.amzn1 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libmagic.so.1()(64bit) for package: file-5.34-3.37.amzn1.x86_64
---> Package file-libs.i686 0:5.30-11.34.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package file-libs.i686 0:5.34-3.37.amzn1 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package file-libs.x86_64 0:5.34-3.37.amzn1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=============================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                     Arch                                     Version                                           Repository                                      Size
=============================================================================================================================================================================================
Updating:
 file                                        x86_64                                   5.34-3.37.amzn1                                   amzn-updates                                    74 k
 file-libs                                   i686                                     5.34-3.37.amzn1                                   amzn-updates                                   670 k
Installing for dependencies:
 file-libs                                   x86_64                                   5.34-3.37.amzn1                                   amzn-updates                                   672 k

Transaction Summary
=============================================================================================================================================================================================
Install             ( 1 Dependent package)
Upgrade  2 Packages

Total size: 1.4 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
Running transaction check
ERROR with transaction check vs depsolve:
file-libs = 5.30-11.34.amzn1 is needed by (installed) file-5.30-11.34.amzn1.i686
```

I tried many methods to bypass this , but non is working , could you kindly help.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! You're doing a partial update. Does it work if you do a full one?

Comment: it doesn't work if i do a full update . ( sudo yum update )

Answer (score 0):

try to investigate why he does not update `file.i686` to version `5.34-3.37.amzn1` also.  If you make sure yum will find that update as well, update should pass.

Comment: update isnt passing